# Cannot connect to the pc in same network

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares, ping

cannot connect to the pc in same network but it can ping each other. My PC is Windows XP other PC is Windows 7. When I open the Shared folder in Network places, It says that \Windows-7 is cannot accessible. please contact system administrator. But I can open the shared folder from Windows-7.

Comment: [Networking home computers running different versions of Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/networking-home-computers-running-different-windows#networking-home-computers-running-different-windows=windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new folder with full access. It may not be safe in some environments so only do so if the network is trusted by you.

On your Windows 7 machine, create a new folder on your desktop. Call it Temp or similar.

Right click, properties, sharing tab. Click Share, in the drop down list choose everyone and add them. Now, give them Read/Write. Click Share.

Now, in the sharing tab still, click on Advanced Sharing. Check Share this folder, click permissions. You should see the option Everyone. Check all 3 Allow boxes.

Click OK. Click OK

Now select Security Tab. Click Edit. Click Add. Type in everyone. Click OK. Select everyone, and then click on Allow Full Control. Click OK. Close the window.

Now, try and access this from your XP machine. If it works, it means your shared folder doesn't have the correct permissions etc. You can use the guide above to try and resolve it.